# How to create a Chatter File from a big base64 string to image png

Tags: images, files, base64

I have a problem with chatter files, I have a webcam theese webcam take a snap and I need upload this snap to chatter entry in a Chatter of custom object.

[image: Image of webcam in chatter]

After of take a picture with the webcam I upload the base64 code of image to a file in Salesforce, but i don't know how to upload the file without attachment this file.  I need use the file in Chatter file.

Some of the errors I get are:

> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, ContentFileName is a required field for
> feed posts of type ContentPost: [ContentFileName]
>
> FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Related Record ID: id value of incorrect
> type: 069Q0000000Y3QHIA0: [RelatedRecordId]

Comment: Some errors 

**FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, ContentFileName is a required field for feed posts of type ContentPost: [ContentFileName]**

Comment: **FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Related Record ID: id value of incorrect type: 069Q0000000Y3QHIA0: [RelatedRecordId]**

Comment: The first error tells you to give this file a name. The second error tells you that the related record id should be of a different type. You have tried to attach it to a contentdocument, but you need to attach it to a contentversion. If you need further help please edit your post, and add the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

How are you posting the file.
To which object on salesforce you are posting ?
Base64 data should be posted to the object ContentDocument or VersionData